# Form.show() in VB.NET returning InvalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

For some reason while I call a specific form in my program it comes up with

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in CinemaBooking2.exe
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

But I'm not sure why. This only suddenly started happening and I'm not sure if it's visual studio messing up or me.

This is the form it is trying to load:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class MainMenu2
  Dim intChildren As Integer = 0
  Dim intStandard As Integer = 0
  Dim intOAP As Integer = 0
  Public intTotal As Integer = 0
  Dim Reader As StreamReader
  Dim Writer As StreamWriter
  Dim booAdmin As Boolean

   Private Sub BtnComingSoon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnComingSoon.Click
       Me.Visible = False
       frmComingSoon.Visible = True
   End Sub

   Private Sub BtnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Me.Hide()
       FrmNowShowing.Show()
   End Sub

   Private Sub FrmMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Reader = New StreamReader("NowShowing.txt")
       LblShowing1.Text = ("Now showing: " & Reader.ReadLine)
       LblShowing2.Text = ("Now showing: " & Reader.ReadLine)

       Reader.Close()

       Reader = New StreamReader("Settings.txt")
       booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine
       Reader.Close()

       If booAdmin = False Then
           BtnRefresh.Hide()
           BtnEdit.Hide()
       End If
   End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBook.Click
       Me.Hide()
       FrmBookings.Show()
   End Sub

    Private Sub CmbChildren_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbChildren.SelectedIndexChanged
       intStandard = CInt(CmbStandard.Text) 'Code for standard combo box
       intTotal = intChildren + intStandard + intOAP
       LblTotal.Text = ("Total: £" & (intChildren * 3.5) + (intStandard * 5.95) + (intOAP * 4.95) & " for " & intTotal & " People.")
       Reader.Close()

       If intTotal > 0 And intTotal <= 100 Then
           BtnBook.Enabled = True
       Else
           BtnBook.Enabled = False
       End If

       Reader = New StreamReader("Settings.txt")
       booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine
       Reader.Close()

       Writer = New StreamWriter("Settings.txt")
       Writer.WriteLine(booAdmin)
       Writer.WriteLine(intTotal)
       Writer.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CmbStandard_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbStandard.SelectedIndexChanged
    intStandard = CInt(CmbStandard.Text) 'Code for standard combo box
    intTotal = intChildren + intStandard + intOAP
    LblTotal.Text = ("Total: £" & (intChildren * 3.5) + (intStandard * 5.95) + (intOAP * 4.95) & " for " & intTotal & " People.")
    Reader.Close()

    If intTotal > 0 And intTotal <= 100 Then
        BtnBook.Enabled = True
    Else
        BtnBook.Enabled = False
    End If

    Reader = New StreamReader("Settings.txt")
    booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine
    Reader.Close()

    Writer = New StreamWriter("Settings.txt")
    Writer.WriteLine(booAdmin)
    Writer.WriteLine(intTotal)
    Writer.Close()
End Sub

   Private Sub CmbOAP_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbOAP.SelectedIndexChanged
       intOAP = CInt(CmbOAP.Text) 'Code for OAP combo box
       intTotal = intChildren + intStandard + intOAP
       LblTotal.Text = ("Total: £" & (intChildren * 3.5) + (intStandard * 5.95) + (intOAP * 4.95) & " for " & intTotal & " People.")
       Reader.Close()

       If intTotal > 0 And intTotal <= 100 Then
           BtnBook.Enabled = True
       Else
           BtnBook.Enabled = False
       End If

       Reader = New StreamReader("Settings.txt")
       booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine
       Reader.Close()

       Writer = New StreamWriter("Settings.txt")
       Writer.WriteLine(booAdmin)
       Writer.WriteLine(intTotal)
       Writer.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This error only appears for this form and no others, so I am unsure of if it is something to do with the form, or if the form has corrupted in some way.

Comment: Which line is causing the issue? The error message is pretty clear, you are trying to convert an empty string into an integer (one the line that is causing the issue). Suggest you switch option strict on to start with - that will probably highlight your error at design time rather than runtime

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Which line in particular does it throw an exception on?

Comment: `booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine`.  Boo.

Comment: The main issue is is that it's springing up on any of the MainMenu2.visible = true lines, but I have no idea why,

Comment: You need to implement null checks, before converting

Comment: It seems that MainMenu2 is Nothing at the point you try to make it visible or it has not benn fully initialized. Why don´t create a new instance and .Show() it when the user clicks the magic Button1?

Comment: @Alex B. Those lines should be ok due to the Default Form Instances that Visual Basic provides.  Thought I agree with you about instantiating the form, it's always a better choice than using the default instance IMHO.

Comment: Start with Option Strict, then stop using default form instances.  Forms are classes, `MainMenu2` is a Class. Rather than `MainMenu2.Show()`, create an instance of it: `Dim frm As New MainMenu2()` then fiddle with that instance var and show it:  `frm.Show()`  More bad than good comes from using default instances

Answer (score 0):

`Reader.ReadLine` returns strings.  I see several places in your code where you are trying to directly assign string values to variables that are not strings. for example:

```
booAdmin = Reader.ReadLine
```

This should probably be:

```
booAdmin = Boolean.Parse(Reader.ReadLine)
```

Any place where you are trying to read an integer should be:

```
someIntegerVariable = Integer.Parse(Reader.Readline)
```

If you want to be even more same, use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, but that will have slightly different semantics.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I'm looking for. The "booAdmin" reader is reading from a text file and the text file would say "true" at that point, so that is not the issue. The main thing I'm thinking of is that visual studio has messed up some how, but I want to make sure before I have to remake the whole thing. And this code was working fine until visual studio thought it would just explode.